# How to find the iOS SDK version that an app is using?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to find a way to see if an app is using a  particular SDK, specifically I need to see if it is using SDK version 12. Is there a way to do this either programmatically or in Xcode? Checking the Base SDK in Xcode just gives me options to set it to "iOS", "macOS" etc.

Comment: Yes programmatically you can always check the iOS version.

Comment: Usually you don't need to know SDK version. What are you trying to achieve that you have to know that SDK version is 12?

Answer (score 5):

Latest Xcode will be having the latest SDK version. I suggest you to check the SDK version from Apple Menu -> About this Mac -> system Report -> Software -> Developer.

Here you can see the SDK version.

Note: As per the AppStore updates, As of June 30, 2020, updates to apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later. So I suggest you update the XCode to the latest version to get the latest SDK version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can type like xcodebuild -showsdks this gives list of sdk's and the current sdk version or else in Xcode

go to Apple icon-> About This Mac-> System Report-> Software-> Developer

you can get your SDK version